# Displaying and intrepreting tab layouts

Tags: tabs, maya, mel

I would like to know if it is possible to 'see' and display the following tab layout maybe through the Attribute Editor etc?
Or how can I interpret it?

In the following, I selected the shader - `ShaderParam_resGen_srf01` but after searching through every attributes I can find in the Attribute Editor, I can neither find the CachedLayouts or the ShaderParamTabDepth elements.

Any ideas?

```
tabLayout -e -selectTabIndex 1"MayaWindow|MainAttributeEditorLayout|formLayout2|AEmenuBarLayout|AErootLayout|AEStackLayout|AErootLayoutPane|AEbaseFormLayout|AEcontrolFormLayout|AttrEdrexShaderSrfFormLayout|scrollLayout121|columnLayout971|frameLayout522|columnLayout976|columnLayout977|MW_ShaderParam_CachedLayouts|MW_ShaderParam_resGen_srf01|ShaderParamTabDepth0";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabLayout` is a UI element, not part of your scene.

From the [documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Commands/tabLayout.html), this command is selecting the first tab of the specified tab layout control.

The long string is the "path" to the control:

```
MayaWindow
MainAttributeEditorLayout
formLayout2
AEmenuBarLayout
AErootLayout
AEStackLayout
AErootLayoutPane
AEbaseFormLayout
AEcontrolFormLayout
AttrEdrexShaderSrfFormLayout
scrollLayout121
columnLayout971
frameLayout522
columnLayout976
columnLayout977
MW_ShaderParam_CachedLayouts
MW_ShaderParam_resGen_srf01
ShaderParamTabDepth0
```

Depending on what you intend by *"interpreting tab layouts,"* other commands listed in the documentation linked above should help you collect the specific information you need. If there's a particular aspect of the layout you want to query, be sure to specify that in your question.

Comment: Perhaps what I really want to ask would be - how do I get the tab, `ShaderParamTabDepth0` (as mentioned in post) to display it out to me? Whether I select the object or paste the 'path' in the `select by name` option, though the latter able to find it but it is not displaying it out for example, the Attribute Editor does not switch its elements etc to the given path.

Comment: @dissidia The problem is that the AE template is dynamic the tab may or may not exist. You can not know for sure. See updateAE

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for getting back to me. Can I ask what is the possibility after running a process that Maya is unable to find a certain tab despite it being there?